# Heroku CLI Not Detecting Git

Tags: git, heroku, ubuntu-17.04, heroku-cli

I am trying to download my git repository off of heroku using

```
heroku git:clone -a my_app
```

but am given the error

```
ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT
```

I read online that this error happens because git was not detected by heroku-cli, but I have git installed. How can I get heroku-cli to detect my git installation? If it's useful, I installed heroku-cli through snap and have installed git through apt-get, and I run ubuntu 17.04 lts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug with snap. Running

```
sudo snap remove heroku
```

and

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

solves the problem.